# where can i see my code in the docker image?

Tags: docker, export, dockerfile, docker-image

I want to put my source code (folder with php files) in my image. That i can use the image to spread out my project.

In my dockerfile i put the following code

```
COPY /codefolder /var/www/html
```

I saved the image and search for my folder and files, but i cant find them. I understood that the saved docker image is a file directory and it builds the hole thing out of it.

```
docker save --output imagename.tar imagename
```

Did i do something wrong or have someone an idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the project folder it was hidden sorry :)